# My desktop doesn't work properly after installing gtk+ libraries

Tags: gui, gtk, .desktop

Yesterday I was trying to install GTK+ libraries(pango,ATk,glib,gtk+,gobjects-introspection). After I installed them every thing was OK. but today when computer boots up, my desktop changed to default desktop(when first time Linux boots up).Right upper icons include power button, clock , etc disappeared and when I try to change the background nothing change. On top of all, when I start MATLAB, a error message box pops up. I know it's something with OpenGl, because I ran it on command line it's working properly.Even I changed desktop environment and for new environment the problems still exist. what's the problem? Is that GTK? How can I Solve it?

Any Help Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Revert the changes you made yesterday.

Open `/var/log/apt/history.log` and look carefully for the exact packages that you installed. You will see the exact commands that you used. Change `install` to `remove` and enter the commands in the reverse order. You should end up with the same installation that you had before.

If your `history.log` happens to be too new, use the most recent zipped one by executing `cd /var/log/apt/; sudo gunzip history.log.1.gz` and scrolling down to the end of `history.log.1`.

Comment: Unfortunately , last command history belongs to first time I boot up the system with new condition.For the record, I know approximately what they were. But problem is more than it. It effects Linux settings. most of system settings disabled.  I don't think installing GTK+ library effect my computer as it is right now. If it was GTK it must effect the system right after installation. isn't it another thing?

Comment: I added a note about what to do if the `history.log` file is too recent. As for whether the system should be affected rightaway, I have no evidence but I don't suppose so. I think you need at least a restart of `lightdm` to see the changes.